# Stop tabbed element closing on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I have snippet of code that opens tabs, however I would like 1 tab to always remain open.

How can I disable the second click on the tab button already open stopping the tab from closing?

So referring to the fiddle, if you click 'Button 1' once, it will show the corresponding tab, but if you click 'Button 1' again it shouldn't close the corresponding tab. Only clicking 'Button 2' will close it also opening it's own tab.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1e4s6z8t/2/)

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tone").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  
    var tab = $(this).attr("id");
    $(".tone__pack").not(tab).css("display", "none");
    $(tab).toggle();
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="tone" id="#tone1">
  Button 1
</div>
<div class="tone__pack" id="tone1">

</div>
<div class="tone" id="#tone2">
  Button 2
</div>
<div class="tone__pack" id="tone2">

</div>
```

CSS

```
.tone {
  display: block;
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.tone__pack {
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) instead of toggle.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/vzrhcfho/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tone").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var tab = $(this).attr("id");
    $(".tone__pack").not(tab).css("display", "none");
    $(tab).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.tone {
  display: block;
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.tone__pack {
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tone" id="#tone1">
  Button 1
</div>
<div class="tone__pack" id="tone1">

</div>
<div class="tone" id="#tone2">
  Button 2
</div>
<div class="tone__pack" id="tone2">

</div>
```

Comment: Wow so simple, I couldn't see that at all before :)

Answer (score 2):

Toggle it only when its pack is hidden, like so:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".tone").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var tab = $(this).attr("id");
            if($(".tone__pack"+tab).is(":hidden")) {
                $(".tone__pack").not(tab).css("display", "none");
                $(tab).toggle();
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
.tone {
    display: block;
    background: blue;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}

.tone__pack {
    display: none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tone" id="#tone1">
    Button 1
</div>
<div class="tone__pack" id="tone1">

</div>
<div class="tone" id="#tone2">
    Button 2
</div>
<div class="tone__pack" id="tone2">

</div>
```

Comment: Another nice solution, I think I prefer swapping out toggle for show, it's a little neater.

Comment: If you want it neater, also change `$(".tone__pack").not(tab).css("display", "none");` to `$(".tone__pack").not(tab).hide();` :)

Answer (score 2):

I modified your code like this,

When the tab is opened, I will add one class to identify that it is already opened.

when again a click event is detected, if it already contains the class, the will not do anything,else I will do as required.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".tone").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var tab = $(this).attr("id");
        $(".tone__pack").not(tab).css("display", "none");

        // removing class, if it is present in any other tab
        $(".tone__pack").not(tab).removeClass("active");

        //if it is already opened, then return
        if($(tab).hasClass("active")){
            return;
        }
        //add identifier for next iterations
        $(tab).addClass("active");

        $(tab).toggle();
      });
    });
```